# Pandas to calculate best and worst rolling average returns

Tags: pandas

Given a list of market data (date, open, high, low, close), how would I create a list of best and worst returns for a given period of exact time?

Where Return = df['close'] / df['close'].shift(exactly 6 years in the past), not just a set number of rows back)

The result - Top 6 Years of best rolling returns:

1. 1/1/1975 - 1/1/1981, 345.2%
2. 2/1/1990 - 1/31/1997, 331.5%
   etc.

Then for the worst returns, the same thing

1. Date-Date, %
2. Date-Date, %
   etc...

I can brute-force do it with just Python and not much Pandas, but I bet there is some cool Pandas way to more elegantly do it.   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try using dataframe .rolling(window =7, center).mean().  this create a window of data over 7 rows and then averages them.